# get name of file used as texture

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, firemonkey

I am trying to get the name of the jpg used as the meterial texture. But not sure how to get it back as a string.

I have this  NOTE: CreateCube[1] is a TCube component in an array

```
CreateCube[1].Material.Texture.CreateFromFile(gamedir+'\pics\'+blocktype);
```

where blocktype is going to be

```
grass.jpg
dirt.jpg
snow.jpg
stone.jpg
```

ect..
but how to get the type once it has been assgined?  Currently I have a string `texture` in the record `cube`.

```
cube.texture := createCube[i].Material.Texture.?????
```

what property will give the name as string?

Comment: I don't think it will be stored somewhere. It's like if you load an image from a file into a `TBitmap`. No one cares from where it comes, everybody wants just data of that bitmap. I would rather think about storing the type of a cube in your record. Something like `Kind` field of type `TCubeKind` where this type would be an enumeration like `(ckGrass, ckDirt, ckSnow, ckStone)`. Storing the cube type in a field could then immediately indicate you which texture did you loaded there.

Comment: @Tlama Sorry should of added this, but createCube[i] is the component TCube. and cube is the record.  So i would need to add the property cubeKind to tcube , thus making a new componet? or can i add a property to an all ready created component, one that comes with firemonkey?

Comment: From a series of questions you've asked I know that you're working on game. I don't what kind of game will this be, but won't you need to know the kind of a cube later on (e.g. when the player will walk through these cubes) ? If you will, then note, that determining a cube type by its texture file name (if it's possible) would be very inefficient. And yes, you can make your own class descendant and add a new property or extend the existing record by the new field indicating the cube kind (I hope that even interposing will work in FMX).

Comment: yes, i am and yes i will need to know.. but was hopeing that TCube would hold the name of the jpg somewhere..  Its a turnbased game so time is not important. but it seems ill look into adding a property to TCube, and wait to see if there is a way to pull the name of the jpg from the tcube.

Comment: Why don't you just remember the name of the file that you passed to the object?

Comment: As other's pointed out, objects with image data aren't 'source aware', they only care about the image data and properties itself (properties such as width, height, etc). Bitmap data, being pushed straight to the VRAM for performance reasons, can't store data such as location/source. The only real solution is to store the source in a variable (and then save it to a file if you want). Alternative solutions includes writing your own `TCube` derivative (such as the answer from 'J...' below) and storing a preset of textures in a property, and the reading that information at runtime.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan cause each object uses 1 of 8 images when created at runtime,  by adding a property i am trying to "remember" it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Following up on the discussion in comments, here is one example of how you might do this - create a new component and add it to your project.  Here I called it `TextureCube` (Right-click the package -> Install.  To change, do a right-click -> uninstall, make your changes, and then right-click -> Install again) :

[image]

```
unit TextureCube;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Classes, FMX.Types, FMX.Types3D, FMX.Objects3D,
  Generics.Collections;

type
  TCubeTexture = (ctGrass, ctDirt, ctSnow, ctStone);

  TTextureSource = Class(TComponent)
    private
      FSelectedTexture : TCubeTexture;
      FTextures : TDictionary<TCubeTexture, TBitmap>;
      function GetTexture : TBitmap;
      procedure SetTexture(setTex : TBitmap);
    public
      constructor Create(AOwner : TComponent); override;
      destructor Destroy; override;
      property Textures : TDictionary<TCubeTexture, TBitmap> read FTextures;
    published
      property SelectedTexture : TCubeTexture read FSelectedTexture write FSelectedTexture;
      property Texture : TBitmap read GetTexture write SetTexture;

  End;

  TTextureCube = class(TCube)
  private
    FType : TCubeTexture;
    FTextureSource : TTextureSource;
    procedure SetCubeTexture(cubeTex : TCubeTexture);
    procedure SetTextureSource(texSource : TTextureSource);
  published
    property CubeType : TCubeTexture read FType write SetCubeTexture;
    property TextureSource : TTextureSource read FTextureSource write SetTextureSource;
  end;

procedure Register;

implementation

procedure Register;
begin
  RegisterComponents('Samples', [TTextureCube]);
  RegisterComponents('Samples', [TTextureSource]);
end;

constructor TTextureSource.Create(AOwner : TComponent);
begin
  inherited;
  FTextures := TDictionary<TCubeTexture, TBitmap>.Create();
end;

destructor TTextureSource.Destroy;
begin
  FTextures.Free;
  inherited;
end;

function TTextureSource.GetTexture : TBitmap;
var tex : TBitmap;
begin
  if FTextures.TryGetValue(FSelectedTexture, tex) then
    result := tex
  else begin
    tex := TBitmap.Create(1,1);
    FTextures.AddOrSetValue(FSelectedTexture, tex);
    result := tex;
  end;
end;

procedure TTextureSource.SetTexture(setTex : TBitmap);
begin
  FTextures.AddOrSetValue(FSelectedTexture, setTex);
end;

procedure TTextureCube.SetCubeTexture(cubeTex: TCubeTexture);
var tex : TBitmap;    
begin
  FType := cubeTex;

  if Assigned(FTextureSource) and
     (FTextureSource.Textures.TryGetValue(cubeTex, tex)) then
    self.Material.Texture := tex
  else
    self.Material.Texture.Clear(0);
end;

procedure TTextureCube.SetTextureSource(texSource: TTextureSource);
begin
  FTextureSource := texSource;
  SetCubeTexture(FType);
end;   

end.
```

This provides a new cube class `TTextureCube` that inherits from `TCube` - the cube adds an enumerated type and can be linked to a `TTextureSource` that provides textures for each type.  Here I've had these added to the `Samples` section in the components toolbar, you can put them anywhere you want.  Drop a TTextureSource and a TTexture cube onto your form and away you go.  This can obviously be improved by having `TTextureCube`s auto-associate with `TTextureSource`s on a form - for now just associate the cube and source :

[image]

I didn't bother making a custom editor/viewer here - in the `TTextureSource` you can just select whatever type and set the texture for that type.  The TTextureSource will save your library of textures associated with each cube type:

[image]

Then for each `TTextureCube` you only need to change the cube type and it will grab the associated texture from the `TTextureSource` :

[image]

As a complete caution - I wrote this up very quickly out of Sunday boredom as an example of how to get started and perhaps how to incorporate a slightly more elegant design.  Obviously I've probably missed a bunch of things, likely haven't cleaned up properly, etc.  I wouldn't use this in production code without a good once-over, some added exception handling, bug check, and tidy.

Comment: @GlenMorse you're quite welcome.  Note, of course, that you only need to go the component route if you want to have a visual component that you can plonk on a form in the IDE and set up visually at design-time.  If you're happy to do everything programmatically then, certainly, you can omit the component registration bit and just include the unit in your own project.

Comment: This seems a little over the top and perhaps pointless to me. There's nothing at all to stop the user also setting the Material directly. At which point the texture type enum value is out of synch. I would not contemplate using this class. I'd just remember the name of the texture file that I used.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan as I said, it's a skeleton of an example, it's not a battle hardened, bulletproof class.  Personally, I think as others have said, the filename is irrelevant.  Why would you want to load a texture twice, ten times, or a thousand times from disk when you can just do it once?  Especially in the context of a game, as it seems this is, I think it makes a lot more sense to start abstracting sooner rather than later.  Grass - can be driven over, then becomes dirt, winter turns it to snow.  Conceivably a block can change from one type to another often; I don't think it 's a stretch.

Comment: Also, who knows what other functionality this block might end up taking on - from step one of a didactic example of how to customize a component it can obviously grow to add a lot more. I know nothing about Glen's game but I know enough about games in general to suspect that a block in-game is going to end up with more functions, properties, etc, than just those describing its texture type.

Comment: Fundamentally, subclassing TCube is wrong. It ties you to the framework, and forces you to expose the entire class which your are extending. Composition is the tool that makes sense here. In fact inheritance is a much overused tool and as a general rule should be avoided.

Comment: +1 for effort. While this is a very nice answer, how does it actually answer the question? I think you went overboard instead of just focusing on the actual question. Answer provided by David is much more suitable, in my opinion.

Comment: @PeterVonča it doesn't answer the explicit question.  Sufficient answer to that was given in comments - that the name of a source file has to be kept track of manually in some way.  From comments we also have determined that Glen is ultimately looking for some way to encapsulate at least one custom cube property and my answer was simply to provide *one* example of how to start doing that.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan your point is well taken and I think in a lot of cases it is true.  In this case, I have very little idea of what Glen has in mind for his program.  Surely there are cases where inheritance is the right answer; I haven't sufficient information about the problem to make that determination.  I've offered this as a single example of how to begin applying an object model to the problem as a solution.  It also affords the opportunity to learn about component design - ultimately it is up to Glen to determine what makes most sense in the context of his specific application.

Comment: Well, I cannot be sure, but my guts tell me inheritance is wrong here

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I actually just sat down to make an example using composition and it's surprisingly more difficult in this case.  The `TCube` actually needs to be exposed to be able to work with it in the normal way (or at all).  A custom component has to at least derive from `TShape3D` to be able to place it into a 3D viewport and have it be rendered, movable, etc.  A private `TCube` field doesn't work because you have to eventually pass it on to a renderer.  Not sure how I would go about a composition model...

Answer (score 1):

The framework does not keep track of the source of the texture. Consequently, there is no way to do what you ask and instead you'll need to keep track of the texture source yourself in your application code.

Comment: Not quite sure about the downvote. Answer seems factually accurate.